# R and MATLAB floor function,do they do the same job?

Tags: r, matlab

I am converting MATLAB code into R

```
xmin=floor( min( min(min(per1),min(per2)) , min(min(per3),min(per4)) ) );
```

Mathworks says

`floor` Round toward negative infinity

Does the R function floor performs the same job?I do not have MATLAB installed,that I can compare the two.

Comment: Yes. Have you read `?floor` ... ?  Was something unclear ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?floor` says

> ‘floor’ takes a single numeric argument ‘x’ and returns a numeric vector containing the largest integers not greater than the corresponding elements of ‘x’.

The [MATLAB help online](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) describes `floor` as "round toward negative infinity", and the actual help text is

> Y = floor(X) rounds each element of X to the nearest integer less than or equal to that element.

Since R's `min()` function takes multiple arguments, I think

```
xmin <- floor( min(per1,per2,per3,per4))
```

should be fine.